# How can I invert the count and set the countdown start time?

Tags: javascript, timer, local-storage, countdown

This JS script performs a progressive count starting from zero. Instead I would like the JS script to count down from a set time (hh.mm.ss). Please what should I change? The script must keep localStorage and the ID startTime.

```html
<div id="display-area"></div>
```

```js
var timer;
var startTime;

function start() {
  startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
  localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  timer = setInterval(clockTick, 100);
}

function clockTick() {
  var currentTime = Date.now(),
    timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - startTime),
    hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
    mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
    secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
    ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
    display = document.getElementById("display-area");

  display.innerHTML =
    (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
    (mins > 9 ? mins : "0" + mins) + ":" +
    (secs > 9 ? secs : "0" + secs);
};
start();
```

The timer works but should count down from a set time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a countdown timer by extending the `clockTick()` calculation so that `timeElapsed` as calculated as *"start time, minus the amount of time that's passed since the countdown began"*.

By introducing `countdownDuration` as `currentTime - startTime`, we can then produce a coutdown timer that counts down from `startTime` by:

```
countdownDuration = currentTime - startTime
timeElapsed = startTime - countdownDuration
```

This can be introduced to your code as follows:

```
function clockTick() {
      const currentTime = Date.now(),
        countdownDuration = currentTime - startTime,
        timeElapsed = new Date(startTime - countdownDuration),
        hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
        mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
        secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
        ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
        display = document.getElementById("display-area");

      display.innerHTML =
        (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
        (mins > 9 ? mins : "0" + mins) + ":" +
        (secs > 9 ? secs : "0" + secs);
};
```

Comment: Please how can I set the countdown start time? For example: 12:30 (hh.mm).